# Oracle Forms Builder: Cannot Execute Query

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using this code fragment:

```
BEGIN
    GO_BLOCK('COMPANY_PRODUCTS');
    EXECUTE_QUERY;
END;
```

in WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE of my form module.

I also changed the text items of my data block into display items.
The problem is that when I start running my form module, it displays an error stating:

```
FRM-40106: No navigable items in destination block.
```

It doesn't have "Enabled" and "Keyboard Navigable" property.

The reason I changed it to display items is because I don't want the user to click and edit the text on the item.
Is there any way can I get through this problem? or should I just stick with text items?

Screenshot: [Form Module on Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Limzd.jpg)

Comment: It's been a long time since I used forms, but maybe one way is to add an extra, small DUMMY text item that the user can navigate to?

Comment: It's been years since I've used this product and I am sure there is method of creating a region that is non-navigable.  But as a quick work-around why not make a single field navigable - will get rid of your error.  Leave all fields as Enabled = False and the user will not be able to make any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your destination block's all item `Display Item`, except leave one of them as `Text Item` ( preferably the first one in the physical sequence of items [topmost or leftmost]). And then, set that text item's `Update Allowed` and `Insert Allowed` property to `No` from `Database` section of `Property Palette`.

Comment: This is cleaner from what I did. Thanks!